# Xamarin creating new android app throws "file not found" error

Tags: android, sdk, ide, xamarin, project

I've downloaded the Xamarin IDE (windows). However whenever I create a new project I get the following error:

[image]

I've checked that the sdk is installed..
[image]

The logs are:

**AndroidTools log**
[2014-12-29 10:00:48.0] INFO: sdk: Looking for Android SDK..

[2014-12-29 10:00:48.0] INFO: sdk:   Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidSdkDirectory found:

```
Path contains adb.exe in \platform-tools (C:\Users\maurice.marinus\Downloads\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk).
```

[2014-12-29 10:00:48.0] INFO: sdk:   Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidSdkDirectory not found.

[2014-12-29 10:00:48.0] INFO: sdk:   Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Xamarin\MonoAndroid\PrivateAndroidSdkPath not found.

[2014-12-29 10:00:48.0] INFO: sdk:   Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Android SDK Tools\Path not found.

[2014-12-29 10:00:48.0] INFO: sdk:   Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Android SDK Tools\Path not found.

[2014-12-29 10:00:48.0] INFO: sdk: Looking for Android NDK..

[2014-12-29 10:00:48.0] INFO: sdk:   Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidNdkDirectory not found.

[2014-12-29 10:00:48.0] INFO: sdk:   Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidNdkDirectory not found.

[2014-12-29 10:00:48.0] INFO: sdk:   Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\JavaSdkDirectory found:

```
Path contains jarsigner.exe in \bin (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05).
```

[2014-12-29 10:00:48.0] INFO: Found Android SDK. API levels: 19

[2014-12-29 10:00:48.0] INFO: Did not find Xamarin.Android

**IDE log**
INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:47Z]: Starting Xamarin Studio 5.5.4 (build 15)

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:47Z]: Running on Microsoft .NET 4.0.30319.33440

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:47Z]: Found GTK# version 2.12.25

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:47Z]: Using GTK+ 2.24.22

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:47Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Core

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:47Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Ide

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:47Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.WindowsPlatform

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:47Z]: Initializing Runtime MS.NET

Starting Xamarin Studio

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:47Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Debugger

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:47Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.SourceEditor2

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:47Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.DesignerSupport

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:47Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Xml

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:47Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.AspNet

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:47Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Refactoring

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:47Z]: Framework .NETPortable,Version=v4.6 has unknown RuntimeVersion 4.6

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:47Z]: Framework .NETPortable,Version=v4.6,Profile=Profile44 has unknown RuntimeVersion 4.6

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:47Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.CSharpBinding

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:47Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.TextTemplating

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:47Z]: Add-in loaded: Xamarin.Forms.Addin

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:47Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.VBBinding

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:47Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.PackageManagement

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:47Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Xamarin.Ide

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:47Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Debugger.Soft

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:47Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.MonoAndroid

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:47Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.NUnit

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:47Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.FSharpBinding

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:47Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.VersionControl

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:47Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Deployment

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:47Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.WebReferences

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:47Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.GtkCore

Loading Workbench

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:47Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.AssemblyBrowser

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:47Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Git

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:47Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.RegexToolkit

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:47Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.DocFood

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:48Z]: ANDROID: sdk: Looking for Android SDK..

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:48Z]: ANDROID: sdk:   Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidSdkDirectory found:

```
Path contains adb.exe in \platform-tools (C:\Users\maurice.marinus\Downloads\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk).
```

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:48Z]: ANDROID: sdk:   Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidSdkDirectory not found.

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:48Z]: ANDROID: sdk:   Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Xamarin\MonoAndroid\PrivateAndroidSdkPath not found.

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:48Z]: ANDROID: sdk:   Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Android SDK Tools\Path not found.

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:48Z]: ANDROID: sdk:   Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Android SDK Tools\Path not found.

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:48Z]: ANDROID: sdk: Looking for Android NDK..

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:48Z]: ANDROID: sdk:   Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidNdkDirectory not found.

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:48Z]: ANDROID: sdk:   Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidNdkDirectory not found.

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:48Z]: ANDROID: sdk:   Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\JavaSdkDirectory found:

```
Path contains jarsigner.exe in \bin (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05).
```

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:48Z]: ANDROID: Found Android SDK. API levels: 19

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:48Z]: ANDROID: Did not find Xamarin.Android

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:48Z]: Xamarin.Android SDK not found, disabling Xamarin.Android addin

```
  Initializing Main Window
```

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:48Z]: Creating DefaultWorkbench

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:48Z]: Updating Welcome Page from 'https://software.xamarin.com/Service/News'.

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:48Z]: Updating Prebuilt Apps from 'https://xamarin.com/PrebuiltApps.xml'.

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:48Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Subversion

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:48Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Subversion.Windows

WARNING [2014-12-29 10:00:48Z]: GLib-GObject-Warning: Attempt to add property __gtksharp_61_MonoDevelop_Components_CellRendererImage::icon-id after class was initialised

Stack trace:

at GLib.Object.gtksharp_register_property(IntPtr type, IntPtr name, IntPtr nick, IntPtr blurb, UInt32 property_id, IntPtr property_type, Boolean can_read, Boolean can_write)

at GLib.Object.AddProperties(GType gtype, Type t)

at GLib.Object.RegisterGType(Type t)

at GLib.Object.LookupGType(Type t)

at GLib.Object.RegisterGType(Type t)

at GLib.Object.LookupGType(Type t)

at GLib.Object.LookupGType()

at Gtk.Widget.OnSizeAllocated(Rectangle allocation)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.WorkbenchWindow.OnSizeAllocated(Rectangle allocation)

at Gtk.Widget.sizeallocated_cb(IntPtr widget, IntPtr allocation)

at Gtk.Application.gtk_main_iteration_do(Boolean blocking)

at Gtk.Application.RunIteration(Boolean blocking)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.DispatchService.RunPendingEvents()

at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeApp.Initialize(IProgressMonitor monitor)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Run(MonoDevelopOptions options)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Main(String[] args, IdeCustomizer customizer)

at Xamarin.Startup.MainClass.Main(String[] args)

WARNING [2014-12-29 10:00:48Z]: GLib-GObject-Warning: Attempt to add property __gtksharp_61_MonoDevelop_Components_CellRendererImage::image-expander-open after class was initialised

Stack trace:

at GLib.Object.gtksharp_register_property(IntPtr type, IntPtr name, IntPtr nick, IntPtr blurb, UInt32 property_id, IntPtr property_type, Boolean can_read, Boolean can_write)

at GLib.Object.AddProperties(GType gtype, Type t)

at GLib.Object.RegisterGType(Type t)

at GLib.Object.LookupGType(Type t)

at GLib.Object.RegisterGType(Type t)

at GLib.Object.LookupGType(Type t)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.DispatchService.RunPendingEvents()

at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeApp.Initialize(IProgressMonitor monitor)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Run(MonoDevelopOptions options)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Main(String[] args, IdeCustomizer customizer)

at Xamarin.Startup.MainClass.Main(String[] args)

WARNING [2014-12-29 10:00:48Z]: GLib-GObject-Warning: Attempt to add property __gtksharp_61_MonoDevelop_Components_CellRendererImage::image-expander-closed after class was initialised

Stack trace:

at GLib.Object.gtksharp_register_property(IntPtr type, IntPtr name, IntPtr nick, IntPtr blurb, UInt32 property_id, IntPtr property_type, Boolean can_read, Boolean can_write)

at GLib.Object.AddProperties(GType gtype, Type t)

at GLib.Object.RegisterGType(Type t)

at GLib.Object.LookupGType(Type t)

at GLib.Object.RegisterGType(Type t)

at GLib.Object.LookupGType(Type t)

at Gtk.Application.gtk_main_iteration_do(Boolean blocking)

at Gtk.Application.RunIteration(Boolean blocking)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.DispatchService.RunPendingEvents()

at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeApp.Initialize(IProgressMonitor monitor)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Run(MonoDevelopOptions options)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Main(String[] args, IdeCustomizer customizer)

at Xamarin.Startup.MainClass.Main(String[] args)

WARNING [2014-12-29 10:00:48Z]: GLib-GObject-Warning: Attempt to add property __gtksharp_62_MonoDevelop_Ide_Gui_Components_ZoomableCellRendererPixbuf::overlay-image-top-left after class was initialised

Stack trace:

at GLib.Object.gtksharp_register_property(IntPtr type, IntPtr name, IntPtr nick, IntPtr blurb, UInt32 property_id, IntPtr property_type, Boolean can_read, Boolean can_write)

at GLib.Object.AddProperties(GType gtype, Type t)

at GLib.Object.RegisterGType(Type t)

at GLib.Object.LookupGType(Type t)

at GLib.Object.LookupGType()

at GLib.Object.CreateNativeObject(String[] names, Value[] vals)

at Gtk.Object.CreateNativeObject(String[] names, Value[] vals)

at Gtk.CellRenderer..ctor()

at Gtk.Application.gtk_main_iteration_do(Boolean blocking)

at Gtk.Application.RunIteration(Boolean blocking)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.DispatchService.RunPendingEvents()

at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeApp.Initialize(IProgressMonitor monitor)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Run(MonoDevelopOptions options)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Main(String[] args, IdeCustomizer customizer)

at Xamarin.Startup.MainClass.Main(String[] args)

WARNING [2014-12-29 10:00:48Z]: GLib-GObject-Warning: Attempt to add property __gtksharp_62_MonoDevelop_Ide_Gui_Components_ZoomableCellRendererPixbuf::overlay-image-top-right after class was initialised

Stack trace:

at GLib.Object.gtksharp_register_property(IntPtr type, IntPtr name, IntPtr nick, IntPtr blurb, UInt32 property_id, IntPtr property_type, Boolean can_read, Boolean can_write)

at GLib.Object.AddProperties(GType gtype, Type t)

at GLib.Object.RegisterGType(Type t)

at GLib.Object.LookupGType(Type t)

at GLib.Object.LookupGType()

at GLib.Object.CreateNativeObject(String[] names, Value[] vals)

at Gtk.Object.CreateNativeObject(String[] names, Value[] vals)

at Gtk.CellRenderer..ctor()

at MonoDevelop.Components.CellRendererImage..ctor()

at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Components.ZoomableCellRendererPixbuf..ctor()

at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Components.ExtensibleTreeView.Initialize(NodeBuilder[] builders, TreePadOption[] options, String contextMenuPath)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Pads.TreeViewPad.Initialize(NodeBuilder[] builders, TreePadOption[] options, String contextMenuPath)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Pads.SolutionPad.Initialize(NodeBuilder[] builders, TreePadOption[] options, String contextMenuPath)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Pads.ProjectPad.ProjectSolutionPad.Initialize(NodeBuilder[] builders, TreePadOption[] options, String contextMenuPath)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.Codons.SolutionPadCodon.b__0()

at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Pads.TreeViewPad.Initialize(IPadWindow container)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.Codons.PadCodon.InitializePadContent(IPadWindow window)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.DefaultWorkbench.CreatePadContent(Boolean force, PadCodon padCodon, PadWindow window, DockItem item)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.DefaultWorkbench.<>c__DisplayClassb.b__7(Object param0, EventArgs param1)

at MonoDevelop.Components.Docking.DockItem.SetupContent(Object ob, EventArgs args)

at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)

at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)

at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)

at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)

at GLib.Signal.ClosureInvokedCB(Object o, ClosureInvokedArgs args)

at GLib.SignalClosure.Invoke(ClosureInvokedArgs args)

at GLib.SignalClosure.MarshalCallback(IntPtr raw_closure, IntPtr return_val, UInt32 n_param_vals, IntPtr param_values, IntPtr invocation_hint, IntPtr marshal_data)

at Gtk.Widget.gtk_widget_show(IntPtr raw)

at Gtk.Widget.Show()

at MonoDevelop.Components.Docking.DockGroup.SizeAllocate(Rectangle newAlloc)

at MonoDevelop.Components.Docking.DockGroup.SizeAllocate(Rectangle newAlloc)

at MonoDevelop.Components.Docking.DockLayout.SizeAllocate(Rectangle rect)

at MonoDevelop.Components.Docking.DockContainer.OnSizeAllocated(Rectangle rect)

at Gtk.Widget.sizeallocated_cb(IntPtr widget, IntPtr allocation)

at Gtk.Widget.gtksharp_widget_base_size_allocate(IntPtr widget, IntPtr allocation)

at Gtk.Widget.OnSizeAllocated(Rectangle allocation)

at MonoDevelop.Components.Docking.DockFrame.OnSizeAllocated(Rectangle allocation)

at Gtk.Widget.sizeallocated_cb(IntPtr widget, IntPtr allocation)

at Gtk.Widget.gtksharp_widget_base_size_allocate(IntPtr widget, IntPtr allocation)

at Gtk.Widget.OnSizeAllocated(Rectangle allocation)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.WorkbenchWindow.OnSizeAllocated(Rectangle allocation)

at Gtk.Widget.sizeallocated_cb(IntPtr widget, IntPtr allocation)

at Gtk.Application.gtk_main_iteration_do(Boolean blocking)

at Gtk.Application.RunIteration(Boolean blocking)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.DispatchService.RunPendingEvents()

at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeApp.Initialize(IProgressMonitor monitor)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Run(MonoDevelopOptions options)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Main(String[] args, IdeCustomizer customizer)

at Xamarin.Startup.MainClass.Main(String[] args)

WARNING [2014-12-29 10:00:48Z]: GLib-GObject-Warning: Attempt to add property __gtksharp_62_MonoDevelop_Ide_Gui_Components_ZoomableCellRendererPixbuf::overlay-image-bottom-left after class was initialised

Stack trace:

at GLib.Object.gtksharp_register_property(IntPtr type, IntPtr name, IntPtr nick, IntPtr blurb, UInt32 property_id, IntPtr property_type, Boolean can_read, Boolean can_write)

at GLib.Object.AddProperties(GType gtype, Type t)

at GLib.Object.RegisterGType(Type t)

at GLib.Object.LookupGType(Type t)

at GLib.Object.LookupGType()

at GLib.Object.CreateNativeObject(String[] names, Value[] vals)

at Gtk.Object.CreateNativeObject(String[] names, Value[] vals)

at Gtk.CellRenderer..ctor()

at MonoDevelop.Components.CellRendererImage..ctor()

at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Components.ZoomableCellRendererPixbuf..ctor()

at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Components.ExtensibleTreeView.Initialize(NodeBuilder[] builders, TreePadOption[] options, String contextMenuPath)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Pads.TreeViewPad.Initialize(NodeBuilder[] builders, TreePadOption[] options, String contextMenuPath)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Pads.SolutionPad.Initialize(NodeBuilder[] builders, TreePadOption[] options, String contextMenuPath)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Pads.ProjectPad.ProjectSolutionPad.Initialize(NodeBuilder[] builders, TreePadOption[] options, String contextMenuPath)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.Codons.SolutionPadCodon.b__0()

at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Pads.TreeViewPad.Initialize(IPadWindow container)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.Codons.PadCodon.InitializePadContent(IPadWindow window)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.DefaultWorkbench.CreatePadContent(Boolean force, PadCodon padCodon, PadWindow window, DockItem item)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.DefaultWorkbench.<>c__DisplayClassb.b__7(Object param0, EventArgs param1)

at MonoDevelop.Components.Docking.DockItem.SetupContent(Object ob, EventArgs args)

at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)

at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)

at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)

at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)

at GLib.Signal.ClosureInvokedCB(Object o, ClosureInvokedArgs args)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.WorkbenchWindow.OnSizeAllocated(Rectangle allocation)

at Gtk.Widget.sizeallocated_cb(IntPtr widget, IntPtr allocation)

at Gtk.Application.gtk_main_iteration_do(Boolean blocking)

at Gtk.Application.RunIteration(Boolean blocking)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.DispatchService.RunPendingEvents()

at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeApp.Initialize(IProgressMonitor monitor)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Run(MonoDevelopOptions options)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Main(String[] args, IdeCustomizer customizer)

at Xamarin.Startup.MainClass.Main(String[] args)

WARNING [2014-12-29 10:00:48Z]: GLib-GObject-Warning: Attempt to add property __gtksharp_62_MonoDevelop_Ide_Gui_Components_ZoomableCellRendererPixbuf::overlay-image-bottom-right after class was initialised

Stack trace:

at GLib.Object.gtksharp_register_property(IntPtr type, IntPtr name, IntPtr nick, IntPtr blurb, UInt32 property_id, IntPtr property_type, Boolean can_read, Boolean can_write)

at GLib.Object.AddProperties(GType gtype, Type t)

at GLib.Object.RegisterGType(Type t)

at GLib.Object.LookupGType(Type t)

at GLib.Object.LookupGType()

at GLib.Object.CreateNativeObject(String[] names, Value[] vals)

at Gtk.Object.CreateNativeObject(String[] names, Value[] vals)

at Gtk.CellRenderer..ctor() 
   at GLib.SignalClosure.Invoke(ClosureInvokedArgs args)

at GLib.SignalClosure.MarshalCallback(IntPtr raw_closure, IntPtr return_val, UInt32 n_param_vals, IntPtr param_values, IntPtr invocation_hint, IntPtr marshal_data)

at Gtk.Widget.gtk_widget_show(IntPtr raw)

at Gtk.Widget.Show()

at MonoDevelop.Components.Docking.DockGroup.SizeAllocate(Rectangle newAlloc)

at MonoDevelop.Components.Docking.DockGroup.SizeAllocate(Rectangle newAlloc)

at MonoDevelop.Components.Docking.DockLayout.SizeAllocate(Rectangle rect)

at MonoDevelop.Components.Docking.DockContainer.OnSizeAllocated(Rectangle rect)

at Gtk.Widget.sizeallocated_cb(IntPtr widget, IntPtr allocation)

at Gtk.Widget.gtksharp_widget_base_size_allocate(IntPtr widget, IntPtr allocation)

at Gtk.Widget.OnSizeAllocated(Rectangle allocation)

at MonoDevelop.Components.Docking.DockFrame.OnSizeAllocated(Rectangle allocation)

at Gtk.Widget.sizeallocated_cb(IntPtr widget, IntPtr allocation)

at Gtk.Widget.gtksharp_widget_base_size_allocate(IntPtr widget, IntPtr allocation)

at Gtk.Widget.OnSizeAllocated(Rectangle allocation)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.WorkbenchWindow.OnSizeAllocated(Rectangle allocation)

at Gtk.Widget.sizeallocated_cb(IntPtr widget, IntPtr allocation)

at Gtk.Application.gtk_main_iteration_do(Boolean blocking)

at Gtk.Application.RunIteration(Boolean blocking)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.DispatchService.RunPendingEvents()

at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeApp.Initialize(IProgressMonitor monitor)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Run(MonoDevelopOptions options)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Main(String[] args, IdeCustomizer customizer)

at Xamarin.Startup.MainClass.Main(String[] args)

WARNING [2014-12-29 10:00:48Z]: GLib-GObject-Warning: Attempt to add property __gtksharp_63_MonoDevelop_Ide_Gui_Components_ExtensibleTreeView+2bCustomCellRendererText::text-markup after class was initialised

Stack trace:

at GLib.Object.gtksharp_register_property(IntPtr type, IntPtr name, IntPtr nick, IntPtr blurb, UInt32 property_id, IntPtr property_type, Boolean can_read, Boolean can_write)

at GLib.Object.AddProperties(GType gtype, Type t)

at GLib.Object.RegisterGType(Type t)

at GLib.Object.LookupGType(Type t)

at GLib.Object.LookupGType()

at GLib.Object.CreateNativeObject(String[] names, Value[] vals)

at Gtk.Object.CreateNativeObject(String[] names, Value[] vals)

at Gtk.CellRendererText..ctor()

at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Components.ExtensibleTreeView.CustomCellRendererText..ctor(ExtensibleTreeView parent)

at Gtk.Widget.Show()

at MonoDevelop.Components.Docking.DockGroup.SizeAllocate(Rectangle newAlloc)

at MonoDevelop.Components.Docking.DockGroup.SizeAllocate(Rectangle newAlloc)

at MonoDevelop.Components.Docking.DockLayout.SizeAllocate(Rectangle rect)

at MonoDevelop.Components.Docking.DockContainer.OnSizeAllocated(Rectangle rect)

at Gtk.Widget.sizeallocated_cb(IntPtr widget, IntPtr allocation)

at Gtk.Widget.gtksharp_widget_base_size_allocate(IntPtr widget, IntPtr allocation)

at Gtk.Widget.OnSizeAllocated(Rectangle allocation)

at MonoDevelop.Components.Docking.DockFrame.OnSizeAllocated(Rectangle allocation)

at Gtk.Widget.sizeallocated_cb(IntPtr widget, IntPtr allocation)

at Gtk.Widget.gtksharp_widget_base_size_allocate(IntPtr widget, IntPtr allocation)

at Gtk.Widget.OnSizeAllocated(Rectangle allocation)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.WorkbenchWindow.OnSizeAllocated(Rectangle allocation)

at Gtk.Widget.sizeallocated_cb(IntPtr widget, IntPtr allocation)

at Gtk.Application.gtk_main_iteration_do(Boolean blocking)

at Gtk.Application.RunIteration(Boolean blocking)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.DispatchService.RunPendingEvents()

at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeApp.Initialize(IProgressMonitor monitor)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Run(MonoDevelopOptions options)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Main(String[] args, IdeCustomizer customizer)

at Xamarin.Startup.MainClass.Main(String[] args)

WARNING [2014-12-29 10:00:48Z]: GLib-GObject-Warning: Attempt to add property __gtksharp_63_MonoDevelop_Ide_Gui_Components_ExtensibleTreeView+2bCustomCellRendererText::show-popup-button after class was initialised

Stack trace:

at GLib.Object.gtksharp_register_property(IntPtr type, IntPtr name, IntPtr nick, IntPtr blurb, UInt32 property_id, IntPtr property_type, Boolean can_read, Boolean can_write)

at GLib.Object.AddProperties(GType gtype, Type t)

at GLib.Object.RegisterGType(Type t)

at GLib.Object.LookupGType(Type t)

at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)

at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)

at GLib.Signal.ClosureInvokedCB(Object o, ClosureInvokedArgs args)

at GLib.SignalClosure.Invoke(ClosureInvokedArgs args)

at GLib.SignalClosure.MarshalCallback(IntPtr raw_closure, IntPtr return_val, UInt32 n_param_vals, IntPtr param_values, IntPtr invocation_hint, IntPtr marshal_data)

at Gtk.Widget.gtk_widget_show(IntPtr raw)

at Gtk.Widget.Show()

at MonoDevelop.Components.Docking.DockGroup.SizeAllocate(Rectangle newAlloc)

at MonoDevelop.Components.Docking.DockGroup.SizeAllocate(Rectangle newAlloc)

at MonoDevelop.Components.Docking.DockLayout.SizeAllocate(Rectangle rect)

at MonoDevelop.Components.Docking.DockContainer.OnSizeAllocated(Rectangle rect)

at Gtk.Widget.sizeallocated_cb(IntPtr widget, IntPtr allocation)

at Gtk.Widget.gtksharp_widget_base_size_allocate(IntPtr widget, IntPtr allocation)

at Gtk.Widget.OnSizeAllocated(Rectangle allocation)

at MonoDevelop.Components.Docking.DockFrame.OnSizeAllocated(Rectangle allocation)

at Gtk.Widget.sizeallocated_cb(IntPtr widget, IntPtr allocation)

at Gtk.Widget.gtksharp_widget_base_size_allocate(IntPtr widget, IntPtr allocation)

at Gtk.Widget.OnSizeAllocated(Rectangle allocation)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.WorkbenchWindow.OnSizeAllocated(Rectangle allocation)

at Gtk.Widget.sizeallocated_cb(IntPtr widget, IntPtr allocation)

at Gtk.Application.gtk_main_iteration_do(Boolean blocking)

at Gtk.Application.RunIteration(Boolean blocking)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.DispatchService.RunPendingEvents()

at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeApp.Initialize(IProgressMonitor monitor)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Run(MonoDevelopOptions options)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Main(String[] args, IdeCustomizer customizer)

at Xamarin.Startup.MainClass.Main(String[] args)

WARNING [2014-12-29 10:00:48Z]: GLib-GObject-Warning: Attempt to add property __gtksharp_63_MonoDevelop_Ide_Gui_Components_ExtensibleTreeView+2bCustomCellRendererText::status-icon after class was initialised

Stack trace:

at GLib.Object.gtksharp_register_property(IntPtr type, IntPtr name, IntPtr nick, IntPtr blurb, UInt32 property_id, IntPtr property_type, Boolean can_read, Boolean can_write)

at GLib.Object.AddProperties(GType gtype, Type t)

at GLib.Object.RegisterGType(Type t)

at MonoDevelop.Components.Docking.DockGroup.SizeAllocate(Rectangle newAlloc)

at MonoDevelop.Components.Docking.DockGroup.SizeAllocate(Rectangle newAlloc)

at MonoDevelop.Components.Docking.DockLayout.SizeAllocate(Rectangle rect)

at MonoDevelop.Components.Docking.DockContainer.OnSizeAllocated(Rectangle rect)

at Gtk.Widget.sizeallocated_cb(IntPtr widget, IntPtr allocation)

at Gtk.Widget.gtksharp_widget_base_size_allocate(IntPtr widget, IntPtr allocation)

at Gtk.Widget.OnSizeAllocated(Rectangle allocation)

at MonoDevelop.Components.Docking.DockFrame.OnSizeAllocated(Rectangle allocation)

at Gtk.Widget.sizeallocated_cb(IntPtr widget, IntPtr allocation)

at Gtk.Widget.gtksharp_widget_base_size_allocate(IntPtr widget, IntPtr allocation)

at Gtk.Widget.OnSizeAllocated(Rectangle allocation)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.WorkbenchWindow.OnSizeAllocated(Rectangle allocation)

at Gtk.Widget.sizeallocated_cb(IntPtr widget, IntPtr allocation)

at Gtk.Application.gtk_main_iteration_do(Boolean blocking)

at Gtk.Application.RunIteration(Boolean blocking)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.DispatchService.RunPendingEvents()

at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeApp.Initialize(IProgressMonitor monitor)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Run(MonoDevelopOptions options)

at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Main(String[] args, IdeCustomizer customizer)

at Xamarin.Startup.MainClass.Main(String[] args)

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:49Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Xamarin.Ide.Windows

node `classlib-gecko' is not defined on the documentation map

node `classlib-taglib-sharp' is not defined on the documentation map

node `classlib-webkit' is not defined on the documentation map

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:50Z]: Prebuilt Apps image already up-to-date.

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:50Z]: Prebuilt Apps image already up-to-date.

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:50Z]: Welcome Page updated.

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:50Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.ILAsmBinding

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:51Z]: Prebuilt Apps already up-to-date.

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:51Z]: Prebuilt Apps updated.

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:52Z]: Prebuilt Apps image already up-to-date.

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:54Z]: Prebuilt Apps image already up-to-date.

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:54Z]: Prebuilt Apps image already up-to-date.

INFO [2014-12-29 10:00:59Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Deployment.Linux

ERROR [2014-12-29 10:00:59Z]: Could not create project of type 'MonoDroid'. Project skipped

ERROR [2014-12-29 10:01:01Z]: Could not update jumplists

System.InvalidOperationException: The file type is not registered with this application.

at Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Taskbar.JumpList.AppendCustomCategories()

at Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Taskbar.JumpList.Refresh()

at MonoDevelop.Platform.JumpList.UpdateJumpList()

at MonoDevelop.Platform.JumpList.OnUpdateTimerEllapsed(Object sender, EventArgs args)

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the Android SDK. Could you check if you have the user rights to access the file location and the file? Try to start Xamarin Studio with Administrator rights to make sure you can access everything.

Comment: Does the Android project get created? If it does not then you will get the file not found error as Xamarin Studio tries to open that file by default for Android projects. I would look in the IDE log to see what the actual error is (Help - Open Log Directory).

Comment: @Martijn. Tried admin rights. Same error

Comment: @MattWard  I've attached the logs to the question

Comment: In the IDE log there are a few errors about not being able to find Xamarin.Android and the Xamarin.Android addin is disabled. I would reinstall Xamarin.Android. You can try to do that by repairing "Xamarin" in Programs and Features. Or by downloading Xamarin.Android from your account - https://store.xamarin.com/account/my/subscription/downloads